# Virtual Machine Server 2003

Tags: windows

I installed some software on my server. It needs an X: drive creating where data files will be stored.

The X: drive points to the C: drive which is where the Terminal Server users will access the software. I created a D: drive with enough space to handle the data, but I don't know how to make the link between the C: drive, the X: drive and the D: drive.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `subst` (substitute) command to do this:

```
subst X: c:\Real\Path\To\Data\Files
```

To remove the mapping use `/D`:

```
subst /D X:
```

(You could also share the folder and map it to X: as a network drive, but that's a lot more overhead that you don't really need in this case.)